# How do I connect to ActiveDirectory from Windows7 running under virtualbox?

Tags: windows-7, windows, active-directory

I have a MBPr and I have installed virtualbox. I setup Windows7 x64 and I can't connect to the work ActiveDirectory.

on a standalone Windows machine, I can run any software as a domain user. But when I try the same on the Windows7 under virtualbox, it wouldn't work.

I can ping ANY work servers including the AD server. I can SSH into our linux boxes. Just I cannot run an app as another AD domain user.

Not sure if this matters but my DNS servers is set to the work's DNS servers.

I've tried NAT and bridged network modes without any luck.

Any ideas how it can be done?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have a link to the domin controller from the virtual machine? e.g. ping

Comment: yes. please see edited post. I added more info.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the Windows 7 machine isnt joined to the domain.  Being on the same network isnt the same as being a part of the domain.  Here are some [directions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/connect-computer-domain#1TC=windows-7) to follow to join the domain.  You may need to talk your Windows administrator for help and/or permission.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the VM has no route to your work network.  My guess is that you set up the VM's network adapter to NAT mode.  That's the default for VBox.  You need to bridge it to your work network instead and then it should work.

Comment: I should've been clearer. Sorry. I can ping the AD servers. My VM box is using work's DNS servers and I've tried both NAT and bridged. just can't run an app as another user. I'll edit my 1st post to reflect this.